# Is it reliably possible to verify an image was taken from a mobile device?

Tags: laravel, mobile, upload

Is it reliably possible to verify if an uploaded image was taken on a mobile device?

I am building an app where I need to verify an uploaded picture was taken on a mobile device. I'm going to assume this isn't possible, and the best way would be to have a tick box on upload that says "I certify that this image was taken on a mobile device".

FYI, for simplicity, assume that "mobile" is a smartphone.

I could read the metadata and then compare this to a list of "matching" mobile devices. I'd imagine this list would be a nightmare to manage and also the original metadata could be lost if the user uploads to a 3rd party service such as Instagram or edits in Photoshop.

I will be using Laravel and Javascript, but I assume this issue is technology agnostic.

Comment: Metadata can easily be spoofed, and any characteristics of a mobile photo can easily be replicated synthetically.

Comment: you can check it from the request from which useragent